# How to check the battery temperature of laptop? How do I know the normal temperature of it?

Tags: battery

How to check battery temperature? How do I know the normal temperature of it?

My OS is Ubuntu, and my laptop is Lenovo G470.

Output of `acpi -t`:

```
Thermal 0: ok, 0.0 degrees C
```

Comment: That's a lightly odd question, that seems to have nothing apparent to do with Ubuntu. Anyway, to find out the temperature, use a thermometer, and to find its normal temperature, search for documentation, or contact the manufacturer.

Comment: @mikewhatever: Thanks for your comment. I would like to know if there is any app / software or indicator for Ubuntu to find out the temperature. I think there is.

Comment: May I ask why you think there is.

Comment: does `cat /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal` give an output?

Comment: @mikewhatever: I have already seen some apps related to the hardware.

Comment: @guntbert: thanks for your comment. This is the output I see of that command: No such file or directory

Comment: ...and can you post links of those that could monitor battery temperatures.

Comment: @mikewhatever: Mike, that's what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`acpi` is used to monitor battery information. Try `acpi -t` for thermal information. Also check out `man acpi` for other options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, acpi tells me this which I do not think is correct: "Thermal 0: ok, 0.0 degrees C". Am I right?

Comment: Can you pot your output of acpi -t.

Comment: pablofiumara@pablofiumara-Lenovo-G470:~$ acpi -t
Thermal 0: ok, 0.0 degrees C

Answer (score 6):

There are many ways to check out the battery temperature of your laptop.

The information regarding your battery status and acpi is stored in `/proc` and `/sys` file system. The easiest way to read this information is using the following commands:

`upower` a command line tool for UPower which provides an interface to enumerate power sources on the system and control system-wide power management.

`acpi` command shows battery status and other ACPI information from `/proc` and `/sys` file system.

**1- Use upower command to check battery status**

Type the following command :

```
$ upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
```

Sample outputs:

```
native-path:          /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0
vendor:               Samsung SDI
model:                DELL 1C75X35
serial:               1820
power supply:         yes
updated:              Tuesday 21 January 2014 06:01:52 PM IST (1757 seconds ago)
has history:          yes
has statistics:       yes
battery
  present:             yes
  rechargeable:        yes
  state:               fully-charged
  energy:              98.235 Wh
  energy-empty:        0 Wh
  energy-full:         98.235 Wh
  energy-full-design:  98.235 Wh
  energy-rate:         0.0111 W
  voltage:             12.864 V
  percentage:          100%
  capacity:            100%
  technology:          lithium-ion
```

**2- Use apci command to check battery status using terminal:**

The acpi command may not be installed by default so use `apt-get command` or `yum command` to install the same:

```
$ sudo yum install
```

OR

```
$ sudo apt-get install acpitool
```

**Linux check battery command**

Type the following command:

```
$ acpi -V
```

Sample outputs:

```
Battery 0: Full, 100%
Battery 0: design capacity 8400 mAh, last full capacity 8044 mAh = 95%
Adapter 0: on-line
Thermal 0: ok, 53.5 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 107.0 degrees C
Cooling 0: LCD 0 of 15
Cooling 1: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 2: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 3: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 4: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 5: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 6: Processor 0 of 10
Cooling 7: Processor 0 of 10
```

To just see status, enter:

```
$ acpi
```

Sample outputs:

```
Battery 0: Charging, 17%, 01:20:06 until charged
```

See ac adapter information:

```
$ acpi -a
```

Sample outputs:

```
Adapter 0: on-line
```

Show thermal information:

```
$ acpi -t
```

Sample outputs:

```
Thermal 0: ok, 39.5 degrees C
```

To use fahrenheit as the temperature unit:

```
$ acpi -tf
```

To use kelvin as the temperature unit:

```
$ acpi -tk
```

Check [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-laptop-battery-status-temperature/) for more info .

Answer (score 6):

Try the program *psensor*. You can get it by typing `sudo apt-get install psensor`. It places all the temperature sensors available to it in a nice compact GUI, graph, and toolbar icon. Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Very nice, like it :D

Comment: No problem. Just cross reference, a lot of the time it can misname sensors. Usually it gets them all. Maybe not for you as my computer is custom built. :)

Comment: Yeah, self build too. It seems to see some that are non existent (0 rpm), but this is neat

Answer (score 4):

The package `lm-sensors` contains a very useful tool:

The command `sensors-detect` tries to find any sensors it knows of, and any other it can recognize.
It does this by various kinds of heuristics, tests, and, if you agree, crude tricks.

The result is saved as a configuration file for the command `sensors`, which can be used to list the sensors that were found, and read the actual values.