# How can I monitor battery temperature?

Tags: 14.04, battery, temperature

Is there an app or a widget for Ubuntu 14.04 that would allow me to keep track of my laptop battery temperature?

So far I've found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/369494/how-to-check-the-battery-temperature-of-laptop-how-do-i-know-the-normal-tempera) thread but the question was never answered.
It's an Inspiron 3521.

Comment: It says "no command apci found, did you mean acpi, xpci?

Comment: Have you installed `acpi`?

Comment: Yes, I used sudo apt-get in the terminal acpi 1.7-1

Comment: acpi -t returns nothing. No error message, nothing

Comment: acpi -b only displays charge and 'rate information unavailable'

Comment: What laptop do you have?

Comment: Inspiron 3521 laptop

Comment: Don't think that has a battery temperature sensor. :/

Comment: Like Tim said, you probably don't have sensor for that. Just get yourself one of those laser thermometers and measure the temperature periodically

Answer (score 0):

Not all laptops and batteries come with a temperature sensor for the battery.  I know of no Dell that does.

You can purchase one of those laser/infrared thermometers and periodically point it at the battery though, and achieve the same general thing.